# get PHP session from webview to android app

Tags: php, android, session, webview

i have an app main activity view  a website which requires login i do all the login stuff on on PHP script but i need to get the id of user logged in to attach notifications from mysql database to my android app anyone can help???

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JavaScript interface and pass the id through that.

Create the interface which will be accessible from the WebView, with a method that will pass the id to your Activity:

```
class JSInterface {

    private MyActivity activity;

    public JSInterface(MyActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setId(int id) {
        // do something with the id
        activity.setId(id);
    }
}
```

Add this to your WebView:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "IDInterface");
```

Now, pass the id from your website:

```
<script style="text/javascript">
    if(window.IDInterface)
        window.IDInterface.setId(<?php echo $id; ?>);
</script>
```

Of course, if you already have an AJAX, WebSoskcet etc notification system for browsers, you can continue to use that and push messages to Java through a JS interface.

Comment: activity.setId(id);
it gives me a hint said cant resolve this method isthis a custom method i can do whatever i want  by the id???

Comment: It's just an example, and for this to work you have to create your own setId(int) in your activity. Of course you can do whatever you want with the id, you don't even have to pass it to your activity.

Comment: Above solution is not worked for me. I had tried but not able to get id value? Tried to print id value using 'Logcat' but it not captured.